# addView to layout with java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to understand how to add views programatically (with java) in Android applications. I created a simple layout (below) to practice that but I struggle to solve the following error:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method addingView() in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'*

[Screenshot from the app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VymyA.png)

My XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.view_create_test_1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="#555555">
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#116677">

        <Button
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="addingView"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addingView (){
        LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top);
        LinearLayout newLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        newLayout.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50));
        top.addView(newLayout,params);
    }

}
```

Please help me out how to solve the error. Thanks

Comment: First u don't need xml layout. Remove top layout. And add some view inside new layout such as image view,  text view etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The issue however is that I want to have a view and add something to it. I will try what you are suggesting, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should come like this

```
public void addingView (View view){ 
        LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top);
        LinearLayout newLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        newLayout.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50));
        top.addView(newLayout,params);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much Karun

Comment: I have done what you suggested and the app is no longer crashing. However, a new view does not appear on the screen. Do I need to call draw() method or any other similar method?? Thanks

Comment: @Adam Based on above function you are only adding "LinearLayout" , that view does not contain any component like textview, edittext etc.. you can add TextView instead of linearlayout and check it put

Answer (score 1):

When you specify an onclick method in Xml, it must contain the corresponding method in your Activity. However you must include the correct parameters. THe View parameter is required.

Change your addingView method declaration to:

```
public void addingView (View v){
```

Your error is however of `changeColor(View)`, which i assume else where, you have done the same thing to the `changeColor` declaration. Add the View parameter to this method also

Comment: Thank you Doomsknight. Yes, you are right. I was trying to addView and failed and then tried the same with changing colour. I pasted the wrong error message.